# Calling UWP api from unmanaged DLL

Tags: c++, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, unmanaged, credential-providers

Currently I have a Credential Provider implemented in C++ and I would like to incorporate BLE communication to it. This is provided in Windows 10 by the UWP class `Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.GattServiceProvider`.

I tried to load to make a UWP DLL implementing the function and load it using `LoadLibrary` but got an `ERROR_NOT_APPCONTAINER`

Is it possible to use the UWP APIs from some unmanaged C++ code?

Answer (score 2):

You can not load UWP dll inside of desktop application. However it is possible to use many UWP APIs directly as they are essentially COM-based. Typically anything not depending on application context and having public activation factory (constructor) can be used. For example see [How to: Activate and Use a Windows Runtime Component Using WRL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973459.aspx).